# Want to use sed to add a blank line in between results

Tags: bash, sed

Imagine I've got a `find` statement that looks like:

```
find . ! -path "*/test/*" -name *.txt -exec grep -Hin "Line" {} \;
```

which generates

```
a.txt:4: Line 4
a.txt:6: Line 6
a.txt:8: Line 8
b.txt:3: Line 3
b.txt:5: Line 5
sub/c.txt:2: Line 2
```

I'd like to format the output so that there are blank lines after each file. My output would look like:

```
a.txt:4: Line 4
a.txt:6: Line 6
a.txt:8: Line 8

b.txt:3: Line 3
b.txt:5: Line 5

sub/c.txt:2: Line 2
```

I'd like to do this by piping the results through a sed (because in reality my `find` is rather more complex and I've already cleaned up the results with other tools).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
find..|whatever..| awk -F: 'NR>1&&$1!=p{print ""}{print;p=$1}'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can append another command, for example one that generates an empty line:

```
find . ! -path "*/test/*" -name *.txt -exec grep -Hin "Line" {} \; -exec echo \;
```

The only downside is that there will be an extra newline at the end as well.

For a sed solution, you can pipe to

```
find ... | sed -r 'N;/^([^:]*):.*\n\1.*$/!{s/\n/\n\n/;P;s/.*\n\n/\n/};P;D'
```

Detailed:

```
N     # Append next line to pattern space

# If the lines up to the first colon don't match
/^([^:]*):.*\n\1.*$/! {
    s/\n/\n\n/      # Insert extra newline
    P               # Print first line
    s/.*\n\n/\n/    # Remove first line up to \n (like 'D' without starting cycle)
}
P     # Print first line of pattern space
D     # Delete first line of pattern space
```

**BSD sed**

To make this run with BSD sed, the `-r` has to be replaced by `-E` (or skipped, but then the parentheses have to be escaped) and there might be an extra semicolon required before the closing brace.

Newlines in regexes should be recognized, but to insert them in replacement strings, one has to use either `'$'\n''` or `'"$(printf '\n')"'`, so the command becomes

```
 sed -E 'N;/^([^:]*):.*\n\1.*$/!{s/\n/'$'\n'$'\n''/;P;s/.*\n\n/'$'\n''/;};P;D'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the grep with awk, e.g.:

```
find . ! -path "*/test/*" -name *.txt -exec \
awk -v OFS=':' 'tolower($0)~/line/{print FILENAME, NR, $0;f=1} END{if(f)print ""}' {} \;
```

and any other cleanup you did could just be made part of the awk script rather than having a whole pile of different commands and pipes or whatever you currently are using.